# How many players can UDK support without Networking

Tags: multiplayer, udk

I've been looking for the answer to this for some time now, but cannot find anything online that is helpful.

What I want to know is the amount of players that the UDK can support on one single machine. An example of this would be golden eye on the N64. On that, you could get 4 players all playing the same game at the same time using split screen. Like in this image:

[image]

Does anyone know is the UDK is capable of doing similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called **split screen**.

It's a relatively big topic to handle in a small reply but is strictly related to how you are managing your viewport, you can find more [online in the wiki](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/UE3%3aGameViewportClient_%28UDK%29).

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. For some reason, the term split screen totally evaded my brain. Thank you.